# Changing domain of integration with measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, integration

Let $\Omega$ a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\Omega.$

Suppose $\Gamma$ is a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and that $F:\Omega to \Gamma$ is a diffeomorphism. Let $G$ take a function defined on $\Omega$ and turn it into a function defined on $\Gamma$.

For $f \in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$, how do I write the integral
$$\int_{\Omega}fd\mu$$ in terms of an integral over $\Gamma$? How do I make the substitution? I don't know because I only how to do it with the Lebesgue measure. Thanks.

(Assume everything is smooth enough)

Comment: What do you mean by "Let $G$ take a function defined on Ω and turn it into a function defined on $\Gamma$."? $Gf = f \circ F^{-1}$?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Yes that is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change of variables formula for general measures is (in the case where $F$ is a bijection)

$$ \int_\Omega f d\mu = \int_\Gamma f \circ F^{-1} d(F_* \mu) $$

where $F_*\mu$ is the pushforward measure $$ (F_*\mu) (A) := \mu(F^{-1}(A)).$$

If you have a preferred $\Sigma$-algebra on $\Gamma$ already, this means you need to require that $F$ is measurable; for example if $\Omega, \Sigma$ are both equipped with the Borel algebra then $F$ being continuous suffices.